# how to get cmake to generate iOS xcframework as an archive

Tags: ios, cmake, xcframework

I am generating a xcframework using cmake commands. Per Apple's documentation, I need to call "xcodebuild archive" command to generate the distributable framework. I realize when I run the "cmake --build", it runs a "xcodebuild build" command.

Is there a way to create a distributable archive using cmake?

Comment: Even i am looking for a support of xcframework in CMake. I found this issues was opened  recently https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21752